# Как преобразовать из BMPString в string

Tags: c#, криптография

Есть строка [BMPString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/about-bmpstring). (Тип BMPString (класс тэга UNIVERSAL, номер тэга 30, форма кодирования — примитивная). Подмножество символов Unicode, каждый символ кодируется всегда 2-мя байтами (октетами).)

```
byte[] nameFileByte = BmpString;
```

var name = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(nameFileByte);

Почему такое преобразование не срабатывает?

Comment: _не срабатывает_ - Что именно происходит? / А если попробовать `BigEndianUnicode`?

Comment: Вот такие символы лежат в переменной name

Comment: 㐰Ȟ ⨞昀椀氀攀㨀㐀㤀㔀㄀ⴀ 开ጄᴄ᠄ሄ☄⸀搀漀挀Ȟ

Comment: `BigEndianUnicode` попробовали? - `file:4951-Р_ГНИВЦ.doc`